# Как локализовать дату в php?

Tags: php, docker

Вывожу дату вот так:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8');
echo date('d-F-Y');
```

Получаю

```
13-February-2023
```

Приложение запущено в Docker контейнере

```
FROM php:8-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER root

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    locales-all \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    nano \
    ruby \
    ruby-dev \
    zsh \
    automake \
    mariadb-client \
    software-properties-common \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
    rsync \
    fzf \
    sudo \
    whois \
    ntp

RUN locale-gen ru_RU.utf8 && dpkg-reconfigure locales-all
```

ввожу команду `locale -a`

и среди прочих вижу нужную локаль

```
...
ro_RO
ro_RO.utf8
ru_RU
ru_RU.cp1251
ru_RU.koi8r
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA
ru_UA.utf8
rw_RW
sa_IN
sah_RU
...
```

Comment: мне не удалось сделать дату по русски никакими ухищрениями с локалью. Надеюсь, что подскажут нормальный вариант, но если у вас тоже не получится :), можете взглянуть сюда https://gist.github.com/splash58/6591dfb7cd2af4c019340cb9afd64d12

Comment: `IntlDateFormatter` ?

Comment: Из [ответа на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328036/php-date-in-foreign-languages-e-g-mar-25-ao%C3%BB-09)  - php -r "setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU'); echo strftime('%A %e %B %Y');"